# Swift - generate one time UUID

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uuid

In swift, this code generate a random uuid...

```
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
```

I have it so when I click on a button, it gets the uuid and prints it to the console, however, when I click the button once more, I get a different uuid. I want to be able to save the UUID that I get on the first click of the button to a string... Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: Move the `let uuid = ...` declaration outside of the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the let uuid declaration outside of your button action every time you click the button you will get another unique id

Answer (score 5):

**UUID is always return value.**

If you want to only one time for your application, then you have to stored into iPhone Keychain. [Check out Keychain tutorial.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html)

Follow the steps to to stored into Keychain:
1) Get data from Keychain.

2) If you don't get data then generate new UUID and stored into Keychain and use it.

3) If you get UUID then directly use it.

You can kaychain [demo](http://hayageek.com/ios-keychain-tutorial/) and [demo](https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password)